# Some problems with module nuxt-simple-sitemap, after build sitemap.xml page not found on server

Tags: module, nuxt.js, sitemap, nuxt3

I am using the module for my nuxt3 app [nuxt-simple-sitemap](https://github.com/harlan-zw/nuxt-simple-sitemap) to create a sitemap from a JSON list of URLs. The dev version of the app works correctly, but when I build the app on the server, I receive the following error message:

```
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization 
Error: Page not found: /sitemap.xml
```

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.